# Add: Object class violation error on adding password policies

Tags: ldap, openldap

While adding the password policy in the openldap file it throws error While running from the command line

```
root@openldap-server:/etc/ldap/slapd.d# ldapadd -D cn=admin,dc=zariga,dc=com -w password -f passwordpolicy.ldif
adding new entry "cn=DefaultPPolicy,ou=Policies,dc=zariga,dc=com"
ldap_add: Object class violation (65)
    additional info: no structural object class provided
```

This is the LDIF file

```
dn: cn=DefaultPPolicy,ou=Policies,dc=zariga,dc=com
cn: DefaultPPolicy
objectClass: pwdPolicy
objectClass: top
pwdAttribute: userPassword
pwdMaxAge: 3024000
pwdExpireWarning: 1814400
pwdInHistory: 4
pwdCheckQuality: 1
pwdMinLength: 9
pwdMaxFailure: 4
pwdLockout: TRUE
pwdLockoutDuration: 600
pwdGraceAuthNLimit: 0
pwdFailureCountInterval: 0
pwdMustChange: TRUE
pwdAllowUserChange: TRUE
pwdSafeModify: FALSE
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're trying to add an object to LDAP with only `pwdPolicy` *objectClass* which is defined as `AUXILIARY` (see [Password Policy for LDAP Directories, ch. 5.1](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-behera-ldap-password-policy-10.html#rfc.section.5.1)) and every object added to LDAP server must have a `STRUCTURAL` *objectClass*.

You need to change your *LDIF* file to include one `STRUCTURAL` *objectClass* like *device* (or any other that you fancy but it's type is `STRUCTURAL`).

For instance:

```
dn: cn=DefaultPPolicy,ou=Policies,dc=zariga,dc=com
cn: DefaultPPolicy
objectClass: device
objectClass: pwdPolicy
objectClass: top
...
```

Comment: The [OpenLDAP manual](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/overlays.html#Password%20Policies) uses `person` as the structural objectClass in its example. But that requires a dummy value for `sn`, so `device` might be a better choice.